# Magento2 grunt issue occurs when running?

Tags: magento2, grunt

I am using Magento2 version CE-2.2.4 i installed npm,grunt on fresh project but when i am running command

> grunt exec:theme

then it create an error 
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>   Warning: Task "exec:theme" not found. Use --force to continue.

I have tried by using force command but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not defined your theme registration for grunt.

Go to dev\tools\grunt\configs\themes.js file from your root directory:

And assign your theme cofiguration as shown below:

```
Themename: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'theme/Themename',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

Then run your command again.

Comment: I have already added my new theme in theme.js file but no luck!

Comment: Please check if your theme name does not have hyphen(-) or underscore(_)

Comment: yes no hyphen(-) and underscore(_) i tried on fresh m2 installation but not wokring with grunt.

Comment: Okay do one thing, go to your root directory. There should be a file "Gruntfile.js.sample". Rename it with Gruntfile.js. then try

Comment: I already did this we need to rename file on root Gruntfile.js,package.json and grunt-config.json.